How to multiarch Docker build on Kubernetes Pod agents?
My organization uses Jenkins on Kubernetes (deployed with Helm; Pod based agents).
With emphasis on pod agent configuration - how can one build multiarchitecture Docker images (like with QEMU & Docker buildx) in Kubernetes?
If somebody could even share some complete reference/example, I'd appreciate that!

when building images you should specify --platform option. example:
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64 -t youdockerimage:latest .

